# Android socket.io Unable to connect through LAN

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I've set up an electron node.js server using socket.io and trying to connect from an android device with socket.io-client. Even though I can ping the local address I'm still getting connect error on connection attempt.

**Server code:**

```
  var port = 5000;
  var io = require('socket.io')(port);
  console.log("Listening on " + port);

  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
  });
```

**Android client code:**

```
 private Socket ioSocket;
 try {
     ioSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.1.35:5000", new IO.Options());
     } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
     }
 ioSocket.connect();
```

Double checked the LAN address of the machine with server running and firewall disabled. Anything else I can try? Open for alternatives as I'm relatively new to android and not even sure whether I should use said package to achieve the connection.

Comment: `"http://192.168.1.35:5000"` -- that looks odd. What does `http` have to do with this?

Comment: I believe this is how you specify address in socket.io, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Sorry! Have you tried reaching your server from another client (e.g., another JS client)?

Comment: yes, works perfectly on node client... on a local host.
Shouldn't be a problem. I tried setting up a http server just now and was able to connect from LAN device.  Java socket still throws an error

Comment: OK, have you tried some `nmap` style app for Android (e.g., [this one](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.kost.nmap.android.networkmapper/)) to confirm that your device can see the open port 5000?

Comment: Looks like android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" was needed in the manifest... Problems tend to sort themselves out once posted here. Thanks anyway!!

Comment: I am surprised that you wound up with a timeout rather than another exception. But, I am glad to hear that it is working for you now!